# How to dispay error message in checkout page when place order

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I'm develop a custom payment method module.When I click place order buttom,page always is loading,can't go to next step.
[image]
When I use other paymen method,I can get error message "Some addresses can't be used due to the configurations for specific countries" like picture.
[image]

I know the error message is from domain.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information.How to display this kind error message in my payment method?

Answer (score 2):

The messageManager object is responsible for messaging in Magento 2. It means that you need to get its instance to write messages. The preferred way is the following: you have to inject this class into your class by adding the following snippet to your __construct method:

```php
protected messageManager;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    ...
){
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    ...
}
```

Now, you can call one of these messages:

```
$this->messageManager->addError(__("Error"));
$this->messageManager->addWarning(__("Warning"));
$this->messageManager->addNotice(__("Notice"));
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Success"));
```